# How to add a parent to multiple disabled objects?

Tags: python, objects, workflow, outliner, select

I select couple of objects in outliner and they are disabled (monitor icon is off). I don't want to enable it. I want to add a parent to those objects. If I select them in outliner and in object property, I set the parent (and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>), it's going set the active one only, not the selected objects.

If the objects are not disabled, then <kbd>Alt</kbd> will work to apply the parent for multiple objects.

Anyone got a solution using python or any other manual way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for *Python*, you can do it in the *Outliner*. Select all objects that you want to parent in the *Outliner*, then with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> drag them onto the object which should be the parent.